# How do I specify relative paths for content such as CSS?

Tags: html, css

When I am linking to any file I have to specify the absolute path looking like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
      href="F:/XmppOld/XAMPP2/htdocs/MAIN_SITE_LAYOUT/css/stylemainpage.css" />
```

I would like to narrow it down to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/stylemainpage.css" />
```

I'm not sure how to. I tried placing `stylemainpage.css` inside the page being viewed, but it didn't work.

Comment: Then move the `css` directory to your webroot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path depends on where you have placed your HTML files

```
HTML
  index.html
CSS
  style.css
```

CSS path in your HTML file would be - `<link href="../CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Edit: in your case the path should be -

```
<link href="../css/stylemainpage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: My html is in F:\XmppOld\XAMPP2\htdocs\MAIN_SITE_LAYOUT\html

and my css in F:\XmppOld\XAMPP2\htdocs\MAIN_SITE_LAYOUT\css

Comment: Use this path. it will work - <link href="../css/stylemainpage.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylemainpage.css"/>` (without the leading slash before `css`)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the CSS file and the HTML pgae in the same folder, then just include the CSS filename. If you want to keep the CSS file in some other folder under the same server root and still want to use relative path names, use `..` and `/`. Use `..` to move up a level, and `/` to move down a level.

Comment: I prefer to separate them. I keep the html and css in separate folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylemainpage.css"/>
```

put your `css` into `css folder`